# Wallpaper broken after version upgrade from 14.10 to 15.04

Tags: upgrade, desktop-background

Yesterday I updated from 14.10 to 15.04. Upon restarting I was greeted by a lovely change to my desktop background.

[image]

I was previously using a default background. I figured it just needed to be refreshed so I changed the wallpaper to another image. However instead of the image I still just got what looks to be a garbled mess of memory. It was however slightly different for every image I tried.

On the login screen the background image appears correctly.

Does anybody know why this is happening or what I might be able to do to fix it?

Comment: Which Desktop Environment are you using? This does not seem like Unity 7.

Comment: It is Unity, I'm using the dark numix circle theme.

Comment: Sorry but I do not have enough reputation points to comment here. Try going to /usr/share/backgrounds and see if the wallpapers JPEGs are OK.

Comment: This looks like a graphics driver problem to me.

Comment: Should I just try updating mesa, ect?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that my upgrade from 14.10 to 15.04 some how got messed up and failed to upgrade a large majority of packages. Re-running

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

seemed to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to insert a custom background, as the default backgrounds may have changed names. Also, if you have Unity tweak tool, hence the numix theme, reinstall it. It may be causing some problems with Unity, but you will keep the icon theme without the program installed. If none of that helps, compiz might have a bug. In this case you may want to consult the launchpad bug database to see if it has been filed.